# Client Side Encryption - Any recommendations / best practices - Point me in the right direction?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, encryption-asymmetric

We have a requirement to encrypt data client side to ensure a 'secure' channel exists between our client's browser and a vendor.

Basic premise is:
Vendor generates a public / private keypair: VendorPub and VendorPriv

Our clients enter sensitive data.
On submit the javascript on the form encrypts the sensitive portions of the data, what gets submitted to our server is VendorPub(SensitiveData).

We submit that package to our vendor as VendorPub(SensitiveData), only they can make use of that data.

Irrespective of key lengths and approved algorithms (RSA and 4096 respectively), and of course the whole thing would be over a SSL connection...

It looks doable, but I haven't mocked it up yet... Any suggestions? Pitfalls?

Our development environment is Visual Studio 2k5/ 2k8 / ASP.net 2.0 or 3.0

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers currently seem to have missed the point of this: "We submit that package to our vendor as VendorPub(SensitiveData), only they can make use of that data".  In other words, you are a relay who treats the data as a black box.

What you are describing is doable if the amount of data is not very large.  Remember, you can't keep the users waiting for your JavaScript to chug along.

RSA4096 is *ridiculously* huge, by the way.  2048 is high-grade at the moment and 3000-whatever is supposed to be good for 30+ years.  But, more power to ya.  A normal way to get around the public-key expense is to encrypt a symmetric (DSA) key using RSA - that way your encryption of the actual data is fast and the only slow part is decrypting the (shorter) key.  Asymmetric-key encryption is **much** slower than symmetric.

Whatever you decide to implement, make sure you get the encryption right in the JS code.

You should also note that this isn't really a way to protect the users from *you*; you control the web server, so you could send the users doctored JavaScript that delivers their private data to you with a key you control.  The users would be unlikely to notice.

Comment: Ok, 3072 and there are quite a few accessible JS RSA implementations. I was kind of hoping to see someone say 'Oh yah, we've done this... This is where it fubared OR and it worked pretty well'

Thanks much

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely doable; although it might be a bit sluggish.

Here's a RSA implementation in JS: http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/

Comment: Your not reading the question.

The goal is to establish a 'Secure Channel from our client to our vendor'  IE we don't want to be able to view the channel.  SSL does not resolve that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be little (if any) reason to do any of this if you're going to use an SSL connection (though I'd prefer TLS).

If you decide to do it anyway, the biggest pitfall with PK cryptography is a MITM attack -- i.e., you don't want to just accept the server's key and encrypt data with it. That will ensure that only the server can read the data, *but* if you haven't verified the identity of the server, you could be sending it to somebody else entirely. This is most of why 1) SSL/TLS connections are slow to set up, and 2) SSL/TLS libraries are big and complicated. Encryption is *much* easier than authentication.

There's no more reason to do this yourself than to do encryption yourself though -- SSL/TLS already do *both* authentication *and* encryption.

Comment: Your not reading the question. The goal is to establish a 'Secure Channel from our client to our vendor' IE we don't want to be able to view the channel. SSL does not resolve that requirement.

Comment: In our case the public key would be pre-generated and would never change so we're reasonably safe from MITM...

Comment: @Gary: I read the question pretty carefully. You simply did a poor job of explaining what you really wanted. What you actually said was "from our client's browser to *a* vendor", not "to *our* vendor" as you've said here. In particular, you did *not* make a clear that the data was coming from a client, passing through your server, then being passed on to the vendor (in fact you still haven't made that entirely clear, but based on what you're saying now, it's at least a fair guess).

Comment: Jerry, that was made 100% clear.  'Our Vendor' means a 3rd party. You did not read the question clearly. 

'Our clients enter sensitive data. On submit the javascript on the form encrypts the sensitive portions of the data, what gets submitted to <b>our server</b> is VendorPub(SensitiveData).

We submit that package to <b>our vendor</b> as VendorPub(SensitiveData), only they can make use of that data.'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the end answer is:
It's doable, reasonably fast and reasonably secure.  However as this was a PCI requirement with the intent to de-scope our environment it was failed because we would still own the encryption method, IE the javascript that would do the encryption would be served from our system.

Thanks to everyone who chimed in.

Gary