# Checksum for SSN

Tags: algorithm, security, validation

I have a project that needs to do validation on the frontend for an American Social Security Number (format `ddd-dd-dddd`). One suggestion would be to use a hash algorithm, but given the tiny character set used (`[0-9]`), this would be disastrous. It would be acceptable to validate with some high probability that a number is correct and allow the backend to do a final `==` check, but I need to do far better than "has nine digits" etc etc.

In my search for better alternatives, I came upon the validation checksums for [ISBN](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/ISBN#ISBN-13) numbers and [UPC](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Universal_Product_Code). These look like a great alternative with a high probability of success on the frontend.

Given those constraints, I have three questions:

1. Is there a way to prove that an algorithm like ISBN13 will work with a different category of data like SSN, or whether it is more or less fit to the purpose from a security perspective? The checksum seems reasonable for my quite large sample of one real SSN, but I'd hate to find out that they aren't generally applicable for some reason.
2. Is this a solved problem somewhere, so that I can simply use a pre-existing validation scheme to take care of the problem?
3. Are there any such algorithms that would also easily accommodate validating the last 4 digits of an SSN without giving up too much extra information?

Thanks as always,
Joe

---

UPDATE:

In response to a question below, a little more detail. I have the customer's SSN as previously entered, stored securely on the backend of the app. What I need to do is verification (to the maximum extent possible) that the customer has entered that same value again on *this* page. The issue is that I need to prevent the information from being incidentally revealed to the frontend in case some non-authorized person is able to access the page.

That is why an MD5/SHA1 hash is inappropriate: namely that it can be used to derive the complete SSN without much difficulty. A checksum (say, modulo 11) provides nearly no information to the frontend while still allowing a high degree of accuracy for the field validation. However, as stated above I have concerns over its general applicability.

Comment: Why would it be disastrous to use sha1?

Comment: @Nick It would be disastrous because you could quite quickly brute force numbers that size. Furthermore, the SSN is a set format, so not all numbers are valid, further reducing the search size. Modern hardware (especially GPUs) can calculate huge numbers of hashes quickly, so this is insufficient security for personally identifying information.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by the question. Aren't you transmitting the SSN in plaintext anyway?

Comment: The request from the server would be encrypted, as would the eventual submission from the user. What I want to prevent here is any attack vector that allows an attacker to steal a portion of the page. Similar to the case where a bank puts an 'xxxxx' mask on certain private data even on authenticated pages.If a customer, for instance, were to leave a session open on a public terminal (or someone found a way to hijack the session), getting to the page should not reveal the customer's data.

Comment: So, why not just only display the last 4 digits?

Comment: The question is in regards to validating the number (which the user is entering as a verification of identity). Displaying the last 4 digits would provide very little space for validation (the other 5 digits would remain entirely unvalidated).

Comment: So, let me clarify this: you don't want to create a checksum, you want to validate the SSN? That's an entirely different question.

Comment: Yes, I want to validate the SSN, on the browser side of the application. If you have a means other than checksum to do so, you'd be giving me a great answer to my second question :)

Comment: This can be restated as a classic cryptography question. How can someone prove that they know a secret, without actually disclosing the secret? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication

Comment: Why aren't you simply sending the SSN to the server (I'm assuming you session is safely encrypted over SSL), and then do simple server-side validation / comparison?  What are the security drawbacks that I'm missing?  [EDIT: As you said elsewhere, the server has the SSN already anyway, so you're not giving it any extra info.]

Comment: The complication over most other algorithms of this type (and I have researched these in the past), is that the 2nd party is hosted on the possibly hostile machine, which means that any information that the 2nd party uses to test the secret is also known to the attacker.

Comment: @Eric because it takes a long time to do a full round trip for a page load, as opposed to using JS to validate the field. Backend validations will exist either way, but it is possible to save users from the extra inconvenience of a complete round trip for simple errors in their entries.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks, I have a better understanding of the issue now.  Still, I worry about the information leakage of any algorithm you come up with.  For ex, a simple mod 11 checksum will still "leak" a 10:1 reduction in SSN search space-- is this leakage (for every user) worth the small round trip savings in the less-often case where user mistypes SSN?  Personally, I'd do minimal client-side validation (I.e., 9 digits, etc), then do normal server-side validation.  Simple & no possibility of info leakage.  If occasional user needs to re-submit, so be it.

Comment: I agree with Eric.  Sound like premature optimization.  You can do a basic sanity check and even some SSN specific pattern validation on the front end just using Regex.  Then just do a full validation -  you have to do it eventually anyway, a function that checks something like an SSN should probably lead to a different page, and most customers will probably get their ssn right the first time.  So it is only the occasional round trip being saved. Round trips and web applications - it is a fact of life.  Surely there is something else in your app that is more worthy of optimization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restating your basic requirements:

- A reasonably strong checksum to protect against simple human errors.
- "Expected" checksum is sent from server -> client, allowing client-side validation.
- Checksum must not reveal too much information about SSN, so as to minimize leakage of sensitive information.

I might propose using a cryptographic has (SHA-1, etc), but do *not* send the complete hash value to the client.  For example, send only the lowest 4 bits of the 160 bit hash result[1].  By sending 4 bits of checksum, your chance of detecting a data entry error are 15/16-- meaning that you'll detect mistakes 93% of the time.  The flip side, though, is that you have "leaked" enough info to reduce their SSN to 1/16 of search space.  It's up to you to decide if the convenience of client-side validation is worth this leakage.

By tuning the number of "checksum" bits sent, you can adjust between convenience to the user (i.e. detecting mistakes) and information leakage.

Finally, given your requirements, I suspect this convenience / leakage tradeoff is an inherent problem:  Certainly, you could use a more sophisticated crypto challenge / response algorithm (as Nick ODell astutely suggests).  However, doing so would require a separate round-trip request-- something you said you were trying to avoid in the first place.

[1] In a good crypto hash function, all output digits are well randomized due to avalanche effect, so the specific digits you choose don't particularly matter-- they're all effectively random.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia is not the best source for this kind of thing, but given that caveat, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number says

> Unlike many similar numbers, no check digit is included.

But before that it mentions some widely used filters:

> The SSA publishes the last group number used for each area number. Since group numbers are allocated in a regular (if unusual) pattern, it is possible to identify an unissued SSN that contains an invalid group number. Despite these measures, many fraudulent SSNs cannot easily be detected using only publicly available information. In order to do so there are many online services that provide SSN validation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mike. While I could probably determine reasonably whether a number is *an* SSN, I need to know if a number is *your* SSN.

Comment: @Joseph, when something at the requesting end of an HTTP connection presents a SSN to you, you want to test whether the presenter is working on behalf of a real US citizen/resident to whom that SSN has been issued and not subsequently revoked?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness. I have the customer's SSN already (stored securely on the backend), and I need to validate that the SSN that they enter on the frontend matches the one I have on record, without revealing to the frontend any more information that I have to (in case the session is compromised in some way).

Comment: @Joseph, ah.  So impersonation is not a problem because you have already done some authentication?  But you don't trust the frontend with a full row in any table of account information?  So you want a function isSsnOfCurrentUser(ssn) that returns a boolean or an async equivalent?  Is eavesdropping a concern or is any channel over which you send the SSN already protected against eavesdropping?

Comment: Impersonation is a potential problem (e.g. if the session is compromised), and you are correct that I don't trust the client with the data. Your function sig is approximately correct, but I am hesitant about async calls because of the time delay for the roundtrip. I would sacrifice some false positives (thought it was correct, was wrong) for speed consideration. Eavesdropping is out of scope of the question, but it is secured over normal browser SSL.

Comment: @Joseph, let's say you have an assymmetric crypt function, the server has the private key and encrypts the SSN and sends it to the client: `crypt(message, publicKey)` -> browser.  The client has the public key and tests whether a user's SSN matches `encryptedSSN === crypt(userEnteredSSN.replace(/\D+/g, ""), publicKey)` is a fairly reliable (depending on key entropy) check.  Then eavesdropping is prevented because only encrypted SSNs are sent over the wire, and the server can decrypt since it has the private key.

Comment: @Joseph, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355160/client-side-encryption-any-recommendations-best-practices-point-me-in-the-r addresses client side encryption options but I can't vouch for their provenance.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution.  Take the number mod 100001 as your checksum.  There is 1/100_000 chance that you'll accidentally get the checksum right with the wrong number (and it will be very resistant to one or two digit mistakes canceling out), and 10,000 possible SSNs that it could be so you have not revealed the SSN to an attacker.

The only drawback is that the 10,000 possible other SSNs are easy to figure out.  If the person can get the last 4 of the SSN from elsewhere, then they can probably figure out the SSN.  If you are concerned about this then you should take the user's SSN number, add a salt, and hash it.  And deliberately use an expensive hash algorithm to do so.  (You can just iterate a cheaper algorithm, like MD5, a fixed number of times to increase the cost.)  Then use only a certain number of bits.  The point here being that while someone can certainly go through all billion possible SSNs to come up with a limited list of possibilities, it will cost them more to do so.  Hopefully enough that they don't bother.